# Empty DataFrame returned when scraping data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape CNBC data from its website about NASDAQ-100 by using BeautifulSoup, but when I try to change the scrape data to DataFrame it shows empty dataframe, columns:[], index:[]

Below is my code :

```
# Importing Libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd

# Create parse tree for parsed pages 
page=requests.get("https://www.cnbc.com/nasdaq-100")

#content=page.content

# Scrape data from specific <div> column
# Title for the data table -> NASDAQ-100

soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
l = []
title=soup.find("div",{"class":"PageHeader-main"}).find("h1").text

table=soup.find_all("table",{"class":"BasicTable-basicTable"})

for items in table:
    for i in range(len(items.find_all("tr"))-1):
        # Gather data
        d = {}
        d["stock_symbol"] = items.find_all("td", {"class":"BasicTable-symbol"})[i].find("a").text
        d["stock_name"] = items.find_all("td", {"class":"BasicTable-name"})[i].text
        d["price"] = items.find_all("td", {"class":"BasicTable-unchanged BasicTable-numData"})[i].text
        d["price_change"] = items.find_all("td", {"class":"BasicTable-quoteDecline"})[i].text
        d["percentage_change"] = items.find_all("td", {"class":"BasicTable-quoteDecline"})[i].text
        # Print ("")
        l.append(d)         
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
print(df)
```

Comment: Do you get values to the "l" list during the iteration of the loop?

Comment: Yup by appending the value d to List l

Comment: @WilliamAdriel check below answer. regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with website which is using `JavaScript` to render it's data once the page loads, So we have 2 options right now.

1. to track the `XHR` request to the `API` where the data is being
   retrieved and fetched.
2. to use `selenium` approach.

> Both solutions is listed below:

```py
import requests
import json

r = requests.get("https://quote.cnbc.com/quote-html-webservice/quote.htm?noform=1&partnerId=2&fund=1&exthrs=0&output=json&symbolType=issue&symbols=153171|172296|74548134|178129|90065764|185811|181702|3145559|8279577|8392868|196573|197784|177124|144094|205778|207106|208206|208526|217706|211573|217809|218647|25427545|223056|225584|226052|226354|90065765|227524|237331|240690|244210|253970|263397|248911|264170|256951|273612|24812378|274516|7186257|9079610|4038959|282500|21167615|282560|283581|284350|50675033|288727|288976|289807&requestMethod=extended").json()

data = json.dumps(r, indent=4)

print(data)

print(r.keys())
```

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.cnbc.com/nasdaq-100")

sleep(2)

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]

print(df)
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

Output: [check-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/1fd29b5f4588a65cd2b6ee962cf14627/result.csv)

Sample:

[image]